# Formatting: Numbering paragraphs of sections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, paragraphs

I have some problems in writing an article with inequalities. What I want to say:

Now, it appears as

```
Cauchy's Inequality

1. Introduction
2. Theorem

Bernoulli's Inequality

3. Introduction
4. Theorem
```

**But**, I want to appear as

```
Cauchy's Inequality

1. Introduction
2. Theorem

Bernoulli's Inequality

1. Introduction
2. Theorem
```

What can I do? 
What I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fullpage,doublespace]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{variations}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lem\u a}

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolar}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Not\u a}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Defini\c{t}ia}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Consecin\c t\u a}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Exemplul}
\newtheorem*{acknowledgements}{Observa\c{t}ie}
```

Comment: Please turn your code sample into a complete MWE (minimum working example) with text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` . Remove the packages that don't affect your question, and make it clear which things are theorems, which are sections ... Then perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: What is "Cauchy's Inequality"? A chapter, a section? And "1. Introduction"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that I canceled the "fullpage" and "doublespace" option. They are needless. (If you want doublespaced lines just use the [`setspace` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace).)

The solution to you actual problem consists in reseting the section counter manually when `\chapter` or `\chapter*` is invoced. (For some reason `\@addtoreset` failed.) Then, you simply need to redefine `\thesection` to get the numbering right, i.e. cancel out the chapter number out of it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\setcounter{section}{0}\ltx@chapter}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Cauchy's Inequality}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Theorem}

\chapter*{Bernoulli's Inequality}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

---

If you need a table of contents, the code above won't be satisfying, as @egreg pointed out. But, you have a bunch of possibilities to fix this. You can simply manually add

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<chaptername>}
```

right after the markup of a specific chapter in your manuscript. This can be easily done automatically in LaTeX by patching `\@schapter` (the macro responsable for the stared version of `\chapter` in the standard classes). Actually this is a little wierd because the stared version is originally supposed to bypass an entry to the ToC and you would have to patch macros that use `\chapter*` in the intended way, like `\tableofcontents` itself to circumvent this behaviour, i.e. if you don't want to have a ToC entry for the ToC.

Hence, it could be more convenient to create a custom macro with its own name, like `\IuliChapter` (or anything else: maybe something that reflects the meaning of this sectiong element, like `\subarticle` or similar). The definition would be identical to the redefinition of `\@schapter`. Consider the following test file to see what is happening:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@@schapter=\@schapter
\renewcommand{\@schapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \ltx@@schapter{#1}}
\let\ltx@tableofcontents=\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup
  \let\@schapter=\ltx@@schapter
  \ltx@tableofcontents
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\IuliChapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \ltx@@schapter{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Cauchy's Inequality}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Theorem}

\IuliChapter{Bernoulli's Inequality}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

If you decide to stick to the last option, the solution can be simplified a lot:

```
...
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IuliChapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \@schapter{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
...
```

Comment: This would require something more if a table of contents needs to be generated.

Comment: A good hint! (Although the OP does not request a ToC :) I added some detail about a fix.